# How we can get the city of current user in sharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, jsom

Hi currently i am working on sharePoint online, Where i need to fetch the Current location (city) of the user and on the basis of that i want to get the temperature of that city. using JScript . Please help.

Comment: Are you managing user's location in Active Directory? Or you just mean the location from where users are browsing site?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to get current location if:

1. User's browser supports HTML5 geolocation API; and
2. User allows to share his/her location to your Application

   ```
       function onLocationUpdate(location) {
           var lat = location.coords.latitude;
           var lng = location.coords.longitude;
           console.log("Current location: " + lat + " " + lng);
       }

       if(navigator.geolocation) {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onLocationUpdate);
       }
       else {
           console.log("navigator.geolocation is not available");
       }
   ```

As a fallback, you can use [this API](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json) to get the Longitude and Latitude from user's IP address.

Once you've got the location, you can make a call to below API passing the Longitude and Latitude you've found:

```
http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=<<Latitude>>&lon=<<Longitude>>&FcstType=json
```

You will get weather data in JSON format, which you can parse temperature data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this SPServices method:

```
var thisUserID = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "Office",
    debug: false
});
```